# Charm++ outside HPC

Tags: parallel-processing, charm++

Does anyone has used Charm++ (http://charm.cs.uiuc.edu/research/charm/) for parallelization outside of HPC (Supercomputers)?

If so, can you tell me about the experience.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm one of the lead developers of Charm++. Our use cases all center on application users getting the highest performance from whatever hardware they have available to them - really, that's what *any* sort of parallel computing is about.

For a very large portion of users, that means simply using all of the cores on a multicore desktop workstation or laptop. Many more also use simple Linux clusters with commodity network hardware (Ethernet or Infiniband). These are usually fairly small systems, up to a few dozen nodes - hardly a supercomputer!

We've demonstrated applications for domains as diverse as [graphics](http://ppl.cs.illinois.edu/papers/11-27), [resource allocation](http://ppl.cs.illinois.edu/research/jetAlloc) (e.g. planning, scheduling, combinatorial optimization), [applied computer vision](http://ppl.cs.illinois.edu/papers/12-02), and more. Other users have demonstrated [volunteer computing](http://apps.man.poznan.pl/trac/xmpp-mpi/export/383/publications/AINA%202011/AINA%202011%20article%20v2/AINA%202011%20article%20v2.pdf) applications using Charm++ (think like SETI@Home or Folding@Home).